# Масштабирование View Controller на iPhone 5

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Всем доброго времени суток. Я столкнулся с такой проблемой: если я запускаю свое iOS приложение на симуляторе, то оно работает отлично, но когда я запускаю его на устройстве (iPhone 5), то сверху и снизу появляются черные полосы, как будто это приложение для 3,5 дюймов. В чем может быть проблема? Даже представить не могу, в чем причина такого поведения. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте скриншот для iPhone 5 в launchImage. По идее xCode 6 должен показывать соответсвующий warning и предлагать validate project settings

Comment: О, получилось, добавил нужное изображение в Launchmage и все сразу заработало. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Прошу прощения, а для iPhone 6 и 6 Plus тоже надо скриншоты добавлять или там все и так нормально? Просто нет сейчас iPhone 6 для проверки

Comment: там можно добавить скриншоты или добавить LaunchScreen.xib, по идее, для iOS 8 по умолчанию используется специальный XIB. Если он не настроен - будут использованы launchImage.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!